# Asprise OCR <error: failed to read pdf. error code: ÿ>

Tags: java, ocr

I'm trying to read a PDF file with images of a scanned document. 
Aspire OCR is giving me this text as the output of the OCR.

```
<error: failed to read pdf. error code: ÿ>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few possible causes: 1) the PDF file doesn't exist; 2) the PDF file is malformed.

We recommend that you should get the latest version of [Asprise OCR and Barcode Recognition Library for Java, C# VB.NET, Python, C/C++ and Delphi](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/ocr-api-for-java-csharp-vb.net.html) and refer to the [Developer’s Guide to Asprise OCR SDK for Java, C# VB.NET, Python, C/C++ & Delphi Pascal](http://asprise.com/ocr/docs/html/asprise-ocr-sdk.html). Alternatively, you can contact our support team directly.